# Sketch polar curve $r^2 = -\sin(2\theta)$

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric

I don't know how to sketch this polar curve since I cannot take the square root of a negative number. I also don't know how to handle the plus/minus resulting from taking the square root.

This is a practice question for a calculus course and I should not be using complex numbers. Also, I shouldn't be using derivatives or integrals for this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the range of $\theta$?

Comment: No range is provided

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The condition $-\sin(2\theta)\geq0$ will give you $\sin(2\theta)\leq0$. In the domain $\theta \in [0,2\pi]\implies2\theta\in[0,4\pi]$, so the inequality has the solution $2\theta \in [\pi,2\pi] \cup [3\pi,4pi] \implies \theta \in [\pi/2,\pi]\cup[3\pi/2,2\pi]$. For $\theta \in [\pi/2,\pi], $ $r^2$ goes from 0 to 1 and back to 0 again like a petal. Similarly you will get a petal in fourth quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

For $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$, you correctly worry that $r$ is not real. It follows that there is no curve in the region $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$ (i.e. the upper right quadrant).

But for, say, $\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi$. $\sin 2\theta \le 0$ so $r$ is defined. You have $r \to 0$ at the endpoints, $r$ is a maximum at $\theta = 3\pi/4$, and so on.

You mention the plus or minus square root. You have to take the *positive* square root, because $r$ is always a positive number.

Comment: Thanks. I've been through examples in my lectures where if r is negative then the curve is in the opposite quadrant. I'm not sure how to reconcile that with what you said about r always being positive.

Comment: I can't speak for the examples you have done as I haven't seen them, but **check** (either yourself, or ask someone). I'm certain that $r$ is always positive.